# Entrada em lista com busca sequencial

Tags: python, funções, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou tentando criar uma função de entrada de variáveis numa lista que só permita entrar termos não contidos já na lista.
Estou tendo dificuldades em encontrar uma solução lógica para isso, eu não posso usar `break` para parar o loop. Não estou tomando erros de identação, estou preso no loop. Alguma sugestão de caminho para a resolução do problema?

```
    lista = []

    def preencheLista(lista,taml):
        for i in range(taml):
            duplicidade = True
            while duplicidade:
                c=float(input("Entre com o termo\n"))
                lista.append(c)
                for i in range(len(lista)):
                    if c == lista[i]:
                        duplicidade = True 
                    else:
                        duplicidade = False     
        if duplicidade:
            print ("Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor")
        else:
            lista.append(c) 

    print (lista)
#print ("Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    preencheLista(lista, 10)
```

Comment: Eu apliquei a formatação de código na sua pergunta através do botão `{}` do editor. Confirme que o código está como era suposto, porque a ultima linha não parece respeitar a indentação que está para trás

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal:

```
def preencheLista( lst, tam ):

    for i in range(tam):

        while True:

            c = float( input("Entre com o termo: ") )

            if c in lst:
                print ("Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor!")
                continue;

            lst.append(c)

            break;

lista = []
preencheLista( lista, 5 )
print(lista);
```

Testando:

```
Entre com o termo: 1.5
Entre com o termo: 2.8
Entre com o termo: 3.0
Entre com o termo: 1.44
Entre com o termo: 1.5
Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor!
Entre com o termo: 3
Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor!
Entre com o termo: 0.3
[1.5, 2.8, 3.0, 1.44, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz usando recursividade, onde executa até que a lista tenha 10 valores, só não tratei a mensagem de repetição "Valor ja existente, digite um novo valor", se quiser ela só colocar um status na função sinalizando quando mostrar a mensagem:

```
lista = []

def preencheLista(lista, contador):
    if contador == 10:
        return

    valor = float(input("Digite um valor: "))

    if valor in lista:
        preencheLista(lista, contador)
    else:
        lista.append(valor)
        preencheLista(lista, contador + 1)

preencheLista(lista, 0)

print(lista)
```